# What is the meaning of the adjective phrase "three-up"?

Tags: meaning, adjectives

In Annie Proulx's short story, the phrase "three-up outfit" appears, used to describe the ranch of one of the characters. I do not know what "three-up" means.

Comment: I suspect the close-votes are because you didn't document the research you've done.   Since your term does not appear in any 'standard' dictionaries (at least in the context of ranches or cowboys) just noting that inside the question may be enough, rather than having that implicit.

Answer (score 9):

> **three-up outfit** A small ranch which, as one cowboy said, "Don't own 'nough beef to hold a barbecue." 
> —  [Western Words: A dictionary of the Range, Cow camp and Trail by RAMON F. ADAMS](https://ia800502.us.archive.org/5/items/westernwordsdict00adam/westernwordsdict00adam.pdf) 
> Pub. 1945 by University of Oklahoma Press.

**EDIT**:

That same dictionary also has:

> **top screw** — The foreman.

so presumably screw = cowboy. And it defines :

> **three-up screw**  — Said of a cowboy working on a small 
>   ranch where three horses are considered 
>   enough for a **mount**.

and

> **mount** — The number of horses assigned to a rider for his personal use during his stay at the ranch...The number of horses assigned a rider depends largely upon the size of the ranch and the kind of country to be worked. Seven to ten head is an average mount..

so extrapolating I think we can say **three-up outfit** could be regarded as a small ranch where each cowboy/rider only needs three or so horses.

I think the **three-up** is unrelated to the number of cowboys and indeed from snippet below, it seems the hero is running the ranch alone, initially at least.

For reference, below is quote in context from Close Range: Wyoming Stories - Page 98:

> [image: He bought and stole half a hundred cows, and with pride in this **three-up outfit**, declared himself a rancher].

Comment: Why *three*? Is it a reference to the (small) number of animals on the ranch?

Comment: @lawrence see edited version

Comment: +1 Good find. I was trying to make it into a cattle brand. There are brands that take the form (number)UP.

Comment: @alancarmack thanks. I have updated to include your comments.

Comment: In  sum, it's just a phrase meaning a small outfit (ranch), and three does not have to be taken literally, in my opinion. A paraphrase might be 'a ranch barely worth the name ranch'.

Comment: In related terminology, a 'three up' is a wagon pulled by three animals (all side by side), e. g. horses, mules or, yes, camels. A 'two up' is a conveyance pulled by two animals, abreast.